# How to use %g and make sure the number of digits after decimal don't exceed 6 in printf?

Tags: c

I want to use %g, meanwhile, I don't want number of digits after decimal exceed 6 .

For example, for 0, I want to show '0' instead of '0.000000'; and for 0.50000001, I want to show '0.5' instead of '0.500000' or '0.50000001'.

How to use the printf format ?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    double a = 0.0; // or 0.50000001

    if(a == 0)
        printf("%.0g\n", a);
    else
        printf("%.2g\n", a);


    return 0;

}
```

Output:

```
0    //if a == 0
0.5  //if a == 0.50000001
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple use `"%g"`.

The default precision after the decimal point is 6 digits.  "Finally, unless the # flag is used, any trailing zeros are removed from the fractional portion of the result and the decimal-point character is removed if there is no fractional portion remaining." C11 §7.21.6.1

```
const char *format = "%g\n";
printf(format, 0.0);
printf(format, 0.50000001);
printf(format, 123.0);
printf(format, 0.123456789);

0
0.5
123
0.123457
```